# Latex package not found

Tags: packages, miktex, installing

I am trying to make a document. Although it's working. But when i am hovering my cursor on any package it's showing the below mentioned error. (See in the figure).

How can i verify is that package installed or not?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Strange… It is to be found  in `/latex/base/`. However you don't need that line (unless your distribution is quite old) since `utf8` is the encoding LaTeX expects by default nowadays.

Comment: It seems to be an issue of the front-end. Which one are you using? Something like Texmaker or TeXStudio or what?

Comment: you only need to compile. LaTeX will complain and issue an error if a package isn't there.

Comment: To add to Ulrike: Depending on your preferences, it may ask you for permission to install the missing package.

Comment: I am using Texstudio

Comment: Compile the document. If it runs through without errors (maybe installing missing packages in the process) restart TeXstudio. It should then mark all packages correctly as installed. (Although, as Bernhard mentions, you don't need this particular package nowadays when using `utf8`.)